# Phrasal verbs dictionary

Tags: discussion

I am looking for accredited online/paper dictionaries for phrasal verbs, if anyone here knows of any good dictionaries of that sort, would you please direct me to them?

Comment: [Oxford Phrasal Verbs Dictionary for learners of English](https://elt.oup.com/catalogue/items/global/dictionaries/9780194317214?cc=it&selLanguage=it) and [COBUILD Phrasal Verbs Dictionary](https://collins.co.uk/product/9780007435487/Collins+COBUILD+Dictionaries+for+Learners+-+COBUILD+Phrasal+Verbs+Dictionary+%5BThird+edition%5D)